# Unions for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ implies Unions for infinity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of sets in $\Omega$.

Prove that if $\bigcup_{n = 1}^N A_n = \bigcup_{n = 1}^N B_n, \forall N \in \mathbb{N}$ then $\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty A_n = \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty B_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.

By definition, there exists $N$ such that $x\in A_N$. So $x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^N A_n$. By hypothesis $x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^N B_n$, and it follow that $x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$

We proved $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$

The other inclusion is exactly the same proof